# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1985,2257) into shape (3024,4032)

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

How can solve that issue?

What is the error here? And how can I fix that? I tried previous code but I faced that value error problem. How can easily fix that?

```
data = np.load('/test.npy')

data.shape
```

```
(3, 1985, 2257)
```

```
cv.imwrite('/zlatan1598797521604a_0.png', data\[2\])

cv.imwrite('/zlatan1598797521604a_1.png', data\[2\])

cv.imwrite('/zlatan1598797521604a_2.png', data\[2\])

cv.imread('/zlatan1598797521604a_0.png', 0)

cv.imread('/zlatan1598797521604a_1.png', 0)

cv.imread('/zlatan1598797521604a_2.png', 0)
```

```
array([[ 78,  55,  58, ..., 170, 180, 181],
       [ 74,  80,  70, ..., 180, 178, 172],
       [ 73,  82,  66, ..., 196, 200, 197],
       ...,
       [  8,   9,  11, ..., 184, 181, 183],
       [  9,  13,  15, ..., 181, 181, 180],
       [ 10,   5,  13, ..., 188, 185, 179]], dtype=uint8)
```

```
Img_example1[:,:,0]=data[0,:,:]
Img_example1[:,:,1]=data[1,:,:]
Img_example1[:,:,2]=data[2,:,:]
plt.imshow(Img_example1)
plt.savefig('zlatan1598797521604a.png')
plt.show()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17764/3038824776.py in <module>
----> 1 Img_example1[:,:,0]=data[0,:,:]
      2 Img_example1[:,:,1]=data[1,:,:]
      3 Img_example1[:,:,2]=data[2,:,:]
      4 plt.imshow(Img_example1)
      5 plt.savefig('zlatan1598797521604a.png')

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1985,2257) into shape (3024,4032)
```

Comment: your data variable has shape `(3, 1985, 2257)` and you are trying to fit this inside the `Img_example1` which has shape `(3024,4032)`. Where in your code are you defining the variable `Img_example1`? You need to create this variable so it has shape `(3, 1985, 2257)`

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre].